# Any diffrence between element.setAttribute element['attr'] element.attr

Tags: javascript, dom

I notice that javascript have several way to set and get attribute with an element.

I am not sure is there any diffrence between them. especially, is there cross browser problems.

Answer (score 4):

Properties and attributes of DOM elements are quite different, and this difference is a source of some confusion.

One problem is that not every attribute maps to a property of the same name. For example, the `value` attribute of an `<input>` element maps to the `defaultValue` property, while the `value` property does not map to any attribute (except in old IE: see below).

The other major reason why you should use properties is that older versions of IE (<=7 and compatibility modes in later versions) implement `getAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` incorrectly. Most attributes are mapped directly to identically-named properties in IE, which has a number of unfortunate effects such as meaning that setting an event handler attribute does not work correctly in IE. The following page has some useful information: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/setAttribute

There are other differences. For example, attributes/properties that deal with URLs have some discrepancies in how relative URLs are handled.

To see the difference between attributes and properties in standards-compliant browsers, consider the value of a text box:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" value="foo">

var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");

console.log(textBox.getAttribute("value")); // "foo"
console.log(textBox.value); // "foo"
console.log(textBox.defaultValue); // "foo"
```

Now, if the user types into the text box or the text box's value is changed using script, we see the property and attribute values diverge:

```
textBox.value = "bar";
console.log(textBox.getAttribute("value")); // "foo"
console.log(textBox.value); // "bar"
console.log(textBox.defaultValue); // "foo"
```

Setting the attribute value will now have no effect on the current value:

```
textBox.setAttribute("value", "baz");
console.log(textBox.getAttribute("value")); // "baz"
console.log(textBox.value); // "bar"
console.log(textBox.defaultValue); // "baz"
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript guarantees `element["attr"]` and `element.attr` to be the same.

`setAttribute()`, however, is not part of the language itself but of the DOM layer above it. There is no guarantee it's the same as a write to the `attr` attribute. It can do more, or even less (i.e. not even update the `attr` attribute of the object and require you to call `getAttribute()` to get the value back).

In practice, the three ways are generally equivalent. Watch out for things like [this](http://www.glennjones.net/Post/809/getAttributehrefbug.htm), though.

Comment: Just thought I'd add: when an attribute doesn't exist, most browsers (Firefox excepted) return `null` when `elm.getAttribute('attr')` is used. Firefox returns a blank string as per the DOM specification. `elm['attr']` and `elm.attr` will always return `undefined` on all browsers, so is more consistent. (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute)