# Style behavior difference between WebKit and Gecko

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, gecko

I was working on a web application when I noticed some peculiar behavior. I have an element with styles applied via the JavaScript `style` property. Afterwards, I tried to remove all of the styles applied on the element with `removeAttribute("style")`. This only works on Gecko. WebKit does nothing.

I have discovered a workaround (using `setAttribute("style", "")` before removing the attribute) but I don't understand why the `setAttribute` would be needed on WebKit but not Gecko. Why?

**I have an example of the behavior [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TaaHh/).** Try commenting out the `setAttribute` line and see how the behavior differs between Gecko and WebKit.

Comment: You're editing a DOM property, not an HTML attribute. Try setting `.style.background` to null. Furthermore, setting an attribute to an empty string is not a reliable way of removing it.

Comment: @Matt: I had assumed that updating the DOM property would also update the HTML attribute to reflect that. Secondly, I'm setting it to empty and then *also* removing it, not just setting it to empty.

Comment: It's not the first time I've seen `removeAttribute` have a different behaviour to `setAttribute` with an empty string; the case I'm thinking of was trying to remove an inline event listener. (In this case `setAttribute` caused a JavaScript strict warning, so not ideal.)

Answer (score 0):

Could it depend on how you set the attribute?

```
var test=document.getElementById("test");
//test.style.background="green";
test.setAttribute("style", "background: green");
test.removeAttribute("style");
```

I comment out the second line, because it is a different way of changing that particular attribute.

Now the fourth line works correctly in webkit (using google chrome dev channel), and when I comment it out, `//test.removeAttribute("style")`, the box remains green from the third line.

Comment: Exactly, I know it depends on how I set the attribute, but my question was why does removing the attribute not work if it was set via the `style` property?

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not setting an *attribute*. You're setting a *property*. Some essential properties like `id` and `className` will update both, but most properties will not update both the attribute and property. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953028/any-diffrence-between-element-setattribute-elementattr-element-attr/3953642#3953642

Comment: @Matt: The interesting thing is that if I put in `alert(test.getAttribute("style"));` right after it sets something with the `style` property, it shows that the attribute is updated appropriately. It also seems to make the `removeAttribute` work as expected (like the `setAttribute`), which itself is unexpected.