# Unable to remove style attribute in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm having troubles removing the styles from my span in Chrome. It can have a bunch of different styles possibly applied to it so I need to just remove it whoesale. Here is an example of the problem,

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjabT/) ***requires chrome**

The `removeAttr('style')` doesn't seem to be removing the style tag. When you open the debug bar though and highlight the span, it starts working perfectly.

Does anyone know why the style is not being removed and how to remove it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Style behavior difference between WebKit and Gecko](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446486/style-behavior-difference-between-webkit-and-gecko)

Comment: I am not sure if it is the removeAttr that is failing http://jsfiddle.net/pjabT/6/ will remove one that is already on there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to try one thing.  Changing the JQuery version to 1.5.2 and it works fine in chrome.  So, it appears it is a bug in the latest version of JQuery.  I suggest you just use the 1.5.2 if you can get away with it or advise Chrome users to change browsers.  You can also do this:

```
 } else {
   $('#s').attr('style');
   $('#s').removeAttr('style');    
 }
```

instead of this:

```
 } else {
   $('#s').removeAttr('style');    
  }
```

for a little bug-fix/hack.

http://jsfiddle.net/pjabT/7/

Comment: Excellent catch, Switching to edge (1.6.3pre) also seems to resolve the issue. I'm going to look for a bug report on it.

Comment: Found it. [Bug#9699](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9699) Thanks for keeping on it. Their solution is `.attr('style', '')` then removing it.

Comment: @Andrew nice find on the bug number.  I didn't know if it was submitted yet.  It just seemed logical for it to be a bug if it worked with a previous version.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to remove it, what about resetting it?

```
$("#someElement").attr("style","");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.style` is probably locked because of its relationship to CSS.

you can obtain the same effect just clearing it with

```
$('#s').attr('style','');
```

Comment: Locked? Do you have any reference to back that assertion up?

Comment: i've been searchng an exact reference, but to no avail. a partial view is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953028/any-diffrence-between-element-setattribute-elementattr-element-attr/3953642#3953642), but what is for sure is that you can't remove the style attribute directly in webkit. i'll look at the source code if i found it

Comment: This is the only reason I can see for it only working on Chrome.  Chrome can be quirky.  I had problems with JS before with it defining a variable as top, it didn't like it.

Comment: @Travis The problem I'm having with accepting this is that when you use the debug bar to look at the element in the DOM, chrome all of a sudden decides that yes it can remove the attribute. So what is changing when you are debugging. If it is locking the attr it should be consistent when debugging as well, but it's not. :(

Comment: at first look on the source, DOMInspector is a different set of code, so it's possible that code from direct js is somewhat sandboxed and DOMInspector isn't. but proving that requires reading a lot of code. isn't some webkit developer around?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the attribute does not get removed, is the .removeAttr() - function applicable for "style"?

Anyhow, I always approach this in a different way. Used the code of your jsFiddle, it works like this

```
var t = true;

setInterval(function(){
    t = !t;
    if(t){
        $('#s').css({color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});
    } else {
        $('#s').attr('style', '');    
    }
}, 1000);
```

All I changed is basically this line

```
$('#s').attr('style', '');
```

where I just set the value of the style attribute to ''

Comment: This works as well as my method below...but this is probably the better of the two.

Comment: It just resets the inline style-attribute, so the styles defined in css-files are in effect again

Answer (score 0):

With the css you are setting css values for this span not attribute

so what you need to do is just change your script into this

```
var t = true;

setInterval(function(){
    t = !t;
    if(t){
        $('#s').attr('style', "color: rgb(255, 0, 0)");
    } else {
        $('#s').removeAttr('style');    
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Should work either way "When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property."-http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I know it is not working put I inserted your code into the fiddle and it doesn't work either.  It probably is a chrome quirk with locking style so it can't be removed as mentioned by Einacio

Answer (score 0):

I am still working on it, but here is a quick fix:

```
var t = true;

setInterval(function(){
t = !t;
  if(t){
     $('#s').css('color','rgb(255, 0, 0)');
   } else {
    $('#s').css('color','rgb(0,0,0)');    
   }
}, 1000);
```

**UPDATE:** It is interesting to note this code works:

var t = true;

```
setInterval(function(){
t = !t;
  if(t){
    $('#s').css({color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});
  } else {
     $('#s').attr('style');
     $('#s').removeAttr('style');    
 }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't know at runtime what styles are there so I can't reset specific styles.

Comment: @Andrew I would have updated this further but I decided to leave it but GNi33 solution seems appropriate for you want to do because it resets styles so I decided to not muck with it further.

Comment: I am out of ideas...this is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You're all right, sort of. The problem is a Webkit with element.removeAttribute('style') which doesn't work consistently.
What jQuery does now (1.6.4) which was probably fixed here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9699 is first setting the style attribute to nothing with element.setAttribute('style', '') and then removing it which seems to solve this.